# Azure Function Proxy to root

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-functions

Anyone know what I am missing here?

I want my proxy to route all requests to my azure function root URL, to my function.

So that this link  https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/
works the same as this link https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/MYShinyNewFunction

Here is my proxy.json

```
    {
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "Root URI to Redirector Trigger Function": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/{*path}",
        "methods": [
          "GET"
        ]
      },
      "backendUri": "https://localhost/{*path}"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "Root URI to Redirector Trigger Function": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/{*path}",
        "methods": [
          "GET"
        ]
      },
      "backendUri": "https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/ActualFunctionName"
    }
  }
}
```

Figured it out